# Asynchronous call to WriteAsync, how do i know when it’s complete?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, async-await

Im writing a file to IsolatedStorageFile with an asynchronous call

```
async void  Base64ToImage()
{
   byte[] data;
   using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
   {
     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("image.p64", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
      {
         data = new byte[isfs.Length];
         isfs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
         isfs.Close();
      }

     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = isf.OpenFile("newReConvertedFile.png", FileMode.Create))
     {
         await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);

 ///////////////////The problem is here, how would i know when WriteAsync is complete to then fire the reload method?
        //reLoadFile();
      }
   }
}
```

i need to know when that WriteAsync is complete to reload that file in another method, how would i go about doing that?

Edit:

Actually my first idea was to save the file to isostorage then sen the image uri to that file, but you can't set uri to isostorage for images or at least i couldn't get to display

My initial thought was to await the method call to reload the file but i get an error “??? does not return a task and cannot be awaited. Consider changing it to return” but I’m not sure how to go about doing this.

The idea here is to convert several images to Base64 (SQLite db), but then load only the selected ones, to display.

the reLoadFile method is as follows

```
async void reLoadFile()
{
    byte[] newFile;
    using (IsolatedStorageFile newFileLoc = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream newFileStream = newFileLoc.OpenFile("newReConvertedFile.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            newFile = new byte[newFileStream.Length];
            newFileStream.Read(newFile, 0, newFile.Length);
            newFileStream.Close();

            var ms = new MemoryStream(newFile); 
            var image = new BitmapImage(); 
            image.SetSource(ms); 
            theImage.Source = image; 
        }
     }
 }
```

I've been searching the posts but i couldn't fine a way to get it to work, because if i call it straight away i get an exception.
What i need to do is open the file convert it from base64 to .png then load the .png file after it has been saved.
If someone could help me out i would appreciate it.

Thanks Bob.

Comment: I don't see why this question was down voted. It presents all of the details necessary to answer the question.

Comment: You should not be using async void, change your method to async Task

Comment: @vcsjones i don't get it either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `reloadFile` does not need to be `async` you only need to use that when you use the `await` keyword inside the method

2) BaseTo64Image needs to be declared as `async Task Base64ToImage()` otherwise the callers of `Base64ToImage()` will not be able to tell when it finishes.

3) `isfs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);` is bad, just because you requested `data.Length` bytes does not mean you will get `data.Length` read in, you need to check the `int` read returns and loop or use `CopyTo(Stream)` to copy to another stream.

4) (to actually answer your question) the keyword `await` will stop the function from processing and wait till the function is complete. When you hit the `await` keyword your `Base64ToImage()` function will return at that point with a `Task` representing the rest of the code in that function, it is up to you what you do with that `Task` returned from the function.

Here is a simplified version of your code using all of the suggestions

```
async Task Base64ToImage()
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = isf.OpenFile("newReConvertedFile.png", FileMode.Create))
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("image.p64", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
         await isfs.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }      

    await ReLoadFile();
}

async Task ReLoadFile()
{


    using (IsolatedStorageFile newFileLoc = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream newFileStream = newFileLoc.OpenFile("newReConvertedFile.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            await newFileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);

            ms.Position = 0;    
            image.SetSource(ms); 
            theImage.Source = image; 
        }
     }
 }
```

However if that is all you are doing, and you are just using `newReConvertedFile.png` as a temporary file you can simplify your code to

```
async Task Base64ToImage()
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("image.p64", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
         var ms = new MemoryStream();
         var image = new BitmapImage();
         await isfs.CopyToAsync(ms);

         ms.Position = 0;
         image.SetSource(ms); 
         theImage.Source = image; 
    }      
}
```

Comment: im not sure i understand u, maybe u could show me an example?

Comment: on the ReloadFile call I'm getting an error here:
var ms = new MemoryStream(newFileStream.Length);
In regards to ur suggestion to simplify even further, i was trying to save it to have a reference of it should app the tombstones, what do u think?

Comment: I can't really help you with the error if you don't tell me what the error is, and why save it, you are making a copy of a file then doing nothing with it other than read it a 2nd time. Unless you have code that is excluded.

Comment: the error `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'byte[]'`
Im still working on it, the images will be stored in SQLite db (base64 format) and then pulled out as needed, i am saving the temp files, to have a ref in case of App deactivate.

Comment: I did not realize `Length` was returning a `Long` just use the no parameter constructor.

Comment: thanks a lot it has been quite a lesson in 5 min :) after i struggled with it all afternoon.
Let me just trouble u with one more thing, the call for Base64ToImage is a btn click, there i have a warning `Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.`
How should i be doing this call?

Comment: Make the click handler `async` too (`private async void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)` or whatever your method is) and call `await Base64ToImage()` when you call the function. Event handlers are the only functions that are allowed to be `async void` every thing else is `async Task` or `async Task<Something>` if it has to return a result.

Comment: I'm still learning c# and trying to get the hang of Async calls (not easy).
Just to clarify are async calls, public, private...
I need to read more on the subject :)
And thanks once again

Comment: async is just a modifier, it does not change public, private, or internal.

Answer (score 2):

The `WriteAsync` method is complete when its returned `Task` completes.

To wait for the task to complete, just `await` it:

```
await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
// WriteAsync is complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call it in next line. await will wait asynchronously till `WriteAsync` completes. That's what the beauty of "async/await" which lets you to write asynchronous code that looks synchronous.

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = isf.OpenFile("newReConvertedFile.png", FileMode.Create))
 {
     await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
     reLoadFile();
  }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: i tried that but i get an exception, i think the file maybe still not saved or still being accessed at that time?

Comment: @BobMachine Just move the `reLoadFile` call after the using statement and check. that should solve your problem

Comment: moving it outside the using, was definitely part of the issue, thanks